# How can I print double-sided with ipptool?

Tags: printing, cups, hp, ipp

I am using the comming line `ipptool` for printing, which is a low-level tool in the CUPS daemon for internet printing.

IPP is a HTTP-based protocol for internet printers, most current LAN-based office printers are supporting it.

I used the following command for print:

```
ipptool -tv -f /path/to/my.pdf ipp://myprinter.on.mylocal.net/ipp/ printfile.ipp
```

Where my `printfile.ipp` defines the characteristics/capabilities of my printer, as follows:

```
{
OPERATION Print-Job
GROUP operation-attributes-tag
ATTR charset attributes-charset utf-8
ATTR language attributes-natural-language en
ATTR uri printer-uri $uri
FILE $filename
}
```

What I know for sure:

1. Single-sided PDF printing is working seamlessly.
2. The printer is a relative ordinary HP office printer,
3. Which is capable to print double-sided without any problem (co-workers with Windows can do that).

I found this printfile with google and seems working, however any deeper digging about its exact format and specification resulted only cloudy specs and docs. Even the name of the file format of this IPP file is unclear for me.

How could I make it to print double-sided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `ipptool`, you can configure a job to use duplex printing by adding

```
ATTR keyword sides two-sided-long-edge
```

or

```
ATTR keyword sides two-sided-short-edge
```

to the job description, depending on the layout you want.

See [RFC 2911](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2911) for details.

Answer (score 3):

While @StephenKitt's answer of course is correct, I want to add a few details:

1. The line he suggested ***HAS*** to appear after the two lines with *`ATTR charset ...`* and *`ATTR language ...`*.
2. The filename can be anything you want. You could name it, for example, `ipp-print-duplex.txt`.
3. The file format specification can be found by reading `man ipptoolfile` on any Linux system. (It ships as part of any package that also ships `ipptool` itself.)
4. Invoke it like this:

   ```
   ipptool -t -v -f my.pdf <device-uri> ipp-print-duplex.txt
   ```

   where you use as the `<device-uri>` value exactly the same string which you get returned when you call `ippfind` (which should also have been shipped alongside `ipptool` itself).

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped a lot. Some HP printers have a habit, that they give an error for this setting. However, it can be set up in their webadmin control panel.

Comment: Looks correct, but when sent to a Xerox Versalink, I get response `sides (unsupported) = unsupported`, so did not work. Nice to hear if it works with other vendors like HP. Please report.

Comment: @sekrett: Never heard of Versalink. You sure it supports duplex printing? You could use this command to query all supported print options directly from any IPP-capable device: `ipptool -t -v <device-uri> get-printer-attributes.test`.

Comment: Yes, it supports, when I print from Windows or through Cups, but directly does not work, it explicitly refuses. The fun part is `get-printer-attributes` claims support of `sides`. Firmware is the latest, in web admin nothing special to configure for IPP.